# Bedeutung von "In der Lage/imstande sein"

Tags: meaning

Ist die Bedeutung von "In der Lage/imstande sein" ähnlich wie die von "können" aber zielt nur auf Fähigkeiten ab?

"Können" hat drei Bedeutungen, oder?

- Fähigkeiten
- Möglichkeit
- erlaubt/berechtigt sein

Comment: @user35816, ich habe die Frage umformuliert. Passt das für dich noch?

Answer (score 2):

*in der Lage / imstande sein* bedeutet können im Sinne der **Fähigkeit**.
[Quelle](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/imstande_sein)

Answer (score 2):

`in der Lage sein` oder `imstande sein` bedeutet können in **zwei** der drei genannten Bedeutungen.

- Fähigkeit
- Möglichkeit

Quelle: [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/imstande_sein)

Comment: Kannst Du mal ein Beispiel geben, in dem _imstande sein_ im Sinne einer Möglichkeit genannt wird? Wenn ich  [diese Beispiele](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=imstande&corpus=korpus21&date-start=2000&date-end=2010&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_asc&limit=10) durchprobiere, finde ich eigentlich keins, wo man _er ist/ich bin usw. imstande_ durch _es ist ihm/mir usw. möglich_ anstatt _er ist/ich bin usw. fähig_ ersetzen könnte.

Comment: Es wäre ihm nun möglich einfach zu fliehen.
Er wäre nun imstande einfach zu fliehen.

Comment: Naja, wie Du meinst. Zumindest für mein Sprachgefühl drückt _imstande_ hier auch die Fähigkeit aus, d.h. die beiden Sätze bedeuten (für mich) nicht das Gleiche: wenn es ihm zu fliehen möglich ist, heißt es noch lange nicht, dass er dazu auch imstande wäre. (bei _in der Lage_ sehe ich allerdings auch beide Bedeutungen: Fähigkeit und Möglichkeit)

Answer (score 0):

in der Lage sein bedeutet die beide Fähigkeit und Möglichkeit

1 Sie sind nicht in der Lage, hier zu rauchen auf Englisch "you can not smoke here" und es bedeutet die Möglichkeit hier

2 Ich bin nicht in der Lage zu rauchen weil mein Burst krank ist. auf Englisch "I can not smoke because I am sick " Hier bedeutet Fähigkeit